# Unable to test Production Push Notifications through AdHoc

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm following Parse's [Push Notification Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) for setting up my Parse app to now be able to send Production push notifications, rather than Development ones, so I can get it ready for the app store. This is covered in section **7.1** in the tutorial.

When I attempt to create an AdHoc provisioning profile, it only works if I create an iOS distribution certificate, when I create an APN production certificate, which is the correct one for this purpose, it shows me this: [image]

If I decide to go ahead and use the iOS distribution certificate from this list instead:
[image]

The provisioning profile is successfully created, but again, it's not using the correct certificate for push notifications. Likewise, because I had to use the distribution one to create the profile, I therefore would have to use the certificates **.p12** file when connecting my Parse Notification settings to this profile. When I attempt to do this, I unsurprisingly receive the following error:

[image]

because I'm uploading the **.p12** of an **iOS Distribution**  certificate, and not the **APN Production iOS** certificate. When I try uploading the **.p12** of the **APN Production iOS** certificate to Parse, it works, but my test iOS device doesn't receive push notifications, because the provisioning profile doesn't use that certificate, as I mentioned earlier.

Am I following the directions incorrectly? Why can't I make a provisioning profile using a Production APN certificate, so that it can work with Parse Push Notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my error was forgetting to set the code signing settings in both Project AND Targets.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used parse, but you have two exact production certificate.

This is an issue, revoke one of them and try again should work!

> the provisioning profile doesn't use that certificate

I think you are misunderstanding what you need to do:

- delete the app from your device
- Build your app signed with distribution certificate
- Install the ad-hoc version of the app on your device

Here is an image to illustrate how the provision profile  works:

[image]

It's a good idea to [check apple docs out](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Also very important to check which provisioning profile you have used to sign and build the app.

Comment: As I mentioned in my more recent post, I did exactly as you said in this answer, and the push notifications still aren't going through.